# Fused location stops sending updates after several hours

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

If I left application turned on for several hours fused location stops sending updates...

I am creating location request with hight priority , here is code :

```
LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setExpirationDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(LOCATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS))
                .setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

Here is client and callback :

```
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            //Update location
        }
    };
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
```

LOCATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS is 5 second, but updates is not always running, I stop and start it manually, when my application needs location. Like it is [documented](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#stop-updates) .

Everything works fine if application is running  one or two hours, but if I left it open for a long time, it stops working....

I requested location updates from Activity on button click, after 10 seconds, I stop location updates manually... If I left it whole night , this means that Activity is alive whole night... after this, when I request location updates again, it is not coming...

Any solution or idea?

Comment: "stops working" be more specific

Comment: location update is not called

Comment: how do you know

Comment: and what is LOCATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS

Comment: @TimCastelijns I use logs, interval is 5 sec.....

Comment: I updated question

Comment: You are probably removing the location updates callback in `onResume`.

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez of course , I don't  :))))

Comment: @Nininea from which component you are requesting updates from activity or background service?

Comment: @HardikMehta from Activity

Comment: @Nininea then it may happen that this activity can be terminated by os due to memory pressure so that location updates are stopped or you are stopping location updates in onPause method or it may happen due to GoogleApi client is disconnected in between

Comment: Is there any update on this task? I still see this happening, specially from Android 12+. But it mostly happens after a day or two..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setExpirationDuration(long millis)
```

from docs:

> Set the duration of this request, in milliseconds.
>
> The duration begins immediately (and not when the request is passed to the location client), so call this method again if the request is re-used at a later time.
>
> The location client will automatically stop updates after the request expires.
>
> The duration includes suspend time. Values less than 0 are allowed, but indicate that the request has already expired.

If you want to receive location updates forever, remove it or set appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

here is MyApplication class :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application  {

  public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
   return activityVisible;
 }

 public static void setVisibilityTrue() {
  activityVisible = true;
 }
```

this is my baseActivity Class :

```
 public static void activityResumed() {
 boolean isScreenOn = true;
 // isScreenOn() method is deprecated API level 21. You should use 
 isInteractive instead:
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
 MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
     isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
 } else {
    isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
 }
 if (isScreenOn) {
    activityVisible = true;
 }
```

}

```
 public static void activityPaused() {
 boolean isScreenOn = true;
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
     isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
 } else {
     isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
 }
 if (isScreenOn) {
     activityVisible = false;
 }

}
private static boolean activityVisible;
```

}

when app is in the background we bring it to foreground , with a timer every 30 seconds we check if app screen is locked or not if it is locked we open the app : `private void bringApplicationToFront(Context context) {
    /**
     * check if motitor screen is Off/On
     * */
    boolean isScreenOn = true;
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) 
     getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    } else {
        isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    }
    if (!isScreenOn) {
        /**
         * check if app  is fore/back ground
         * */
        boolean isInForeBackground = false;
        try {
            isInForeBackground = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!isInForeBackground) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, 
        ActivitySplash.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
         0, notificationIntent, 0);
            try {
                pendingIntent.send();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}`

I think if the app comes to foreground its priority is high then it can use gps all the time .

the tricky part is when app is in the background and screen is locked the onPause() is called after reopening the app (bring it to foreground) means activityVisible is set to false (means not visible which is not true), actually it is correct but it is not what I wanted , to solve this problem I never let the activityVisible to be set when screen is locked and when app is reopened in splash I set the activityVisible to true.

hope it could help ...